# Authorization: How can I add multiple session into one in C#?

Tags: asp.net

This is my code and I've set permissions so if a user id is 132 he/she will see button1, etc. The problem is that I have multiple of these permission throughout the webpage (for other functions) and if I need to add someone I have to change it in 5/6 places rather than one. Can I combine all the sessions into one master session? Also I dont want to create a table in the DB

```
 else if (Session["UserId"].Equals("132") || (Session["UserId"].Equals("210"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("41")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("103"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("404")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("130"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("92")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("490"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("172")))
            {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you seriously don't want to create a permission table, the next-best thing you can do is a "helper" class

```
public static class PermissionChecker 
{
    public static bool HasPermissionViewButtons(string userId) 
    {
        return (new [] { "123", "210", ...}).Contains(userId);
    }
}
```

and then call this Method

```
if (PermissionChecker.HasPermissionViewButtons(Session["UserId"])) { ... }
```

please keep in mind, this is highly error prone! the user-ids should not be mapped directly to permissions in code.